# Using google charts with Backbone and require.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs, google-visualization

I would like to use Google charts (for some charts) with my backbone project. I am using require.js and now I have question how to load Google API using require.js.

Here is the official [Google site](https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/quick_start) that gives basic instructions how to use it

Reading upon this subject, I have found many references to a require.js plugin that was found in [here](https://github.com/millermedeiros/requirejs-plugins)

That is Mr. Miller Medeiros :)
I have problem with using this script:

This is what I have done.

1. I downloaded async script from Mr. Miller GIT rep, and placed it in my project
2. In my main.js I have included it as follows:

   ```
   baseURL: '.',
   paths: {
       underscore  : 'lib/underscore',
       backbone    : 'lib/backbone',
       async       : 'lib/async',
       babysitter  : 'lib/backbone.babysitter',
       wreqr       : 'lib/backbone.wreqr',
       marionette  : 'lib/backbone.marionette',
       handlebars  : 'lib/handlebars',
       jquery      : 'lib/jquery', 
   },
   ```
3. Now my question is how do I use it?
   All of my js files have the following structure:

   ```
   define([
   'marionette',
   //more defines...    

   ], function(
     Marionette
   //more calls here
   ) {
   ```
4. How do I make Google code available to my application? I just need to use it on one or two places and that's it :)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As far I can see from the author examples, the usage seems to be:

```
require([
    'async!http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false'
], function()
{
    //Google maps is available and all components are ready to use.
    var map = new google.maps.Map( 
    ...
```

so in your case could be something like this

```
require([
    'async!https://www.google.com/jsapi'
], function()
{
    google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['corechart']});
    ...
```

or as defined also [here](https://github.com/millermedeiros/requirejs-plugins/blob/master/examples/goog.html)

```
require(['goog!visualization,1,packages:[corechart,geochart]', 'goog!search,1'], function()
{
    // visualization + corechart + geochart + search are loaded
    // code copied from google charts docs:
    // http://code.google.com/apis/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart.html
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
```

You need to load goog.js from repo (requirejs-plugins/src), put it in your lib folder and define it in your paths as:

```
paths : {
    //alias to plugins
    async : 'lib/async',
    goog : ' lib/goog',
```

Comment: You answer shed more light on my issue. However, I am confused here... All the examples are using require, while I am using define... how do I integrate it with my examples?

Comment: I think, in this case, you can use require as well as define, cause your are not using a name to `define` your module but only dependencies and callback. Give it a try

Comment: As you can see internally define is: `define = function (name, deps, callback) { ... if (typeof name !== 'string') {
            //Adjust args appropriately
            callback = deps;
            deps = name;
            name = null;
        }`

Comment: So in case the name is missing all attributes following switch position, that's your case. I think.

Comment: Just a very small and poor explanation. If you don't need to use your module in other parts of your application u can use `require` (just to do some stuff with the right deps); Otherwise use `define`, so you define a module, you check deps, do some stuff and return a value to **define** your module, maybe needed (by using `define` or `require`) then somewhere

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the library is already AMD compatible, you can use it by simply pointing to it (path and all) right in your define() call:

```
define([
 'marionette',
 'path/to/google/charts'
], function(Marionette, GoogleCharts) {
  // Stuff
});
```

Now, if its not AMD compatible, you'll need to use a [shim](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-shim).

Comment: The second paramater in define... can I point to google online API location?

Comment: Problem here is that google charts location is not a simple script, its a collection of definitions that load other scripts as well